# C# ReSharper Formatting Method Invocations

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I'm looking to format method invocations with complex parameters (nested 'new' and/or nested lambdas) such that the final ')' or `}` and `)` are on the same line.

Consider the following code (nested 'new' case):

```cs
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(parm1,
    parm2, parm3));
```

Should format to:

```
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(
    parm1, 
    parm2, 
    parm3
));
```

Likewise, when dealing with a nested lambda, consider the following:

```cs
Task.Run(() => { var result = myClass.DoStuff(); myResultCollector.Collect(result); });
```

Should format to:

```cs
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var result = myClass.DoStuff();
    myResultCollector.Collect(result);
});
```

In both cases, what I end up with instead:

```cs
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(
        parm1, 
        parm2, 
        parm3
    )
);

Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var result = myClass.DoStuff();
        myResultCollector.Collect(result);
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Initial sample edited to be multi-line, not long enough to invoke chop rules, ironically making the `ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName` completely irrelevant to the examples  shown.

It may help to share my method invocation settings. I think what I want just isn't possible so for now I'm working with what requires the least effort. Here's the relevant section from R#'s C# code formatting settings panel
[image]
[image]
Given the above two samples I end up with the following, which is OK, I can just add a line break after the last parameter as follows

```cs
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(parm1,
    parm2,
    parm3));

// if entered like this, it yields the desired format upon auto-formatting
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(parm1, parm2, parm3
));

//yields
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(parm1,
    parm2,
    parm3
));
```

While not ideal it works for now. I suspect the root cause is `Prefer wrap before ")" in invocation`, which ironically is what I want to happen, but only once for the outter most expression, not for each sub-expression (such as new syntax as an argument). Enabling that option turns the desired format into:

```
myClass.MyMethod(new ThisIsAMuchLongerThanUsualClassName(parm1,
        parm2,
        parm3
    )
);
```